# how to make phpMyAdmin import datetime correctly from csv?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I've been provided a csv file which contains an export of a client's database table. Two of the columns are dates, and in the file they're formatted as mm/dd/yyyy.

```
ID | ActivateDate
-----------------
1  | 05/22/2010
2  | 10/01/2010
```

Our mySQL database that I need to import them into has those columns defined as datetime, with a default value of null. When I use the import function in phpMyAdmin, it's setting all the date columns in the imported records to 0000-00-00 00:00:00, regardless of whether there's any value in the import file.

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to get the ActivateDate column in the database to be set to 2010-05-22 00:00:00 instead of 0000-00-00 00:00:00?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If at all possible, I'd import those values into a varchar column `fake_column` first, and then push them over into the real column  `real_column`using [`STR_TO_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).

```
UPDATE tablename SET real_column = STR_TO_DATE(fake_column, '%m/%d/%Y');
```

[Reference on how to build the format string](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Comment: Thanks. So I did the import into temp varchar columns, and that worked. But when I did this: UPDATE arrc_Voucher SET `ActivatedDT` = STR_TO_DATE(ActivatedDTtmp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%s') the ActivatedDT column (the real datetime column) is still null and the myPHPAdmin query area says "0 rows affected". Any ideas?

Comment: @EmmyS no, if your incoming format is `05/22/2010`, you need to use the notation I showed above. It's the definition for the *incoming* data

Comment: Thanks. I thought because you gave the reference about building the format string that I was supposed to change the format.

Comment: @Emmy you're welcome. I *thought* about not including it because it could be misleading :) Will listen to my thoughts next time.

Answer (score 11):

If you have the file in a CSV format open it up into excel.

1. Right click the column heading that contains the dates.
2. Select Format Cells
3. Click the "Custom" category
4. Paste "yyyy-mm-dd h:mm:ss" in the input box.
5. Save the document.
6. Import into table using phpMyAdmin

Comment: This is exactly how I did it too after trying and failing with the accepted answer. This seemed easier to me..

Comment: Not an option, if you don't have excel, and/or csv file is too big

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8):

I was just able to do this by changing the date fields to Custom format yy-mm-dd.  ( FORMAT > CELLS > Custom > yy-mm-dd.

I had to save it as an XLS but was able to import it correctly directly into the table using PHPMyAdmin version 3.3.10

Comment: Is4680, that's fine until you have more than say 65,000 rows.  It gets too big for most versions of Office to handle.

Comment: Thank you. This is the best solution. But I did it with format->cells->date then by selecting the UK

Comment: Bes solution, should be the approved answer.