# Date format from CSV to MySql

Tags: mysql, date, import

I have not cracked why I cannot get this simple thing working as I am sure it does. I refer to importing CSV data into MySQL using the import function of phpmyadmin.

I have a CSV with the following data (as seen when opened in XL):

```
DSH0000000001   06-03-2014  2999-12-31  n   y   12.00   13.00   15.00
DSH0000000002   03-06-2014  2999-12-31  n   y   8.00    8.50    9.00
DSH0000000003   03-06-2014  2999-12-31  n   y   12.00   13.00   15.00
```

When I open the CSV in wordpad it looks like this:

```
DSH0000000001,6/03/2014,31/12/2999,n,y,12,13,15
DSH0000000002,6/03/2014,31/12/2999,n,y,8,8.5,9
DSH0000000003,6/03/2014,31/12/2999,n,y,12,13,15
```

When I import it into my table it comes up like this:

```
DSH0000000001 0000-00-00 0000-00-00 n y 12.00 13.00 15.00
DSH0000000002 0000-00-00 0000-00-00 n y 8.00 8.50 9.00
DSH0000000003 0000-00-00 0000-00-00 n y 12.00 13.00 15.00
```

The fields in MySQL are DATE just like in XL. Surely I do not have to import it in steps like [it says here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712554/how-to-make-phpmyadmin-import-datetime-correctly-from-csv)?

What is wrong with my set up? Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you want to follow those steps? Those dates aren't in MySQL format and you need to convert them.

Comment: Surely there is some way to set up the dates in XL to go straight into MySql without mucking about with middle steps in the import? It is 2014 after all... I cannot understand why a "date" is not a "date"?

Comment: A date isn't a date when it is a string. Also, date value can be ambiguous. is 3/6/2014 March 6th or June 3rd? That's why there are standard formats for dates. So you know when you have one and can act accordingly. It us up to users to make sure the proper formats are used otherwise intermediate steps have to be taken for those dates to be dates.

Comment: In those steps, there is an answer pointing to formatting cells in XL:  Custom format yy-mm-dd. ( FORMAT > CELLS > Custom > yy-mm-dd. That might be what you want (not tested).

Comment: Hi koriander, I have used the step and it has worked but it rejects timestamps next (another import, different table).

Comment: Hi John Conde, I understand. I am now having the issue importing timestamps, formates with =TEXT(NOW(),"yy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss") and I have used the format supplied in the other post.